# node js webpack Changes made to pages not displaying in chrome after rebuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm taking an online course and created an app for a previous project and ran it on localhost:8000.  I did use service workers if that matters.  Now I'm working on a new app, also on localhost:8000 but it is still showing the previous app.  If I go to the page in firefox, I see the app I'm working on but I need to see it in chrome.  I never opened my previous app before in firefox, which is probably why I can see the new one.

Any idea what's happening here and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably check your terminals if you have left your previous server running, and change the `port` to view your current project.